# Hide math in align and replace with variable white space

Tags: math-mode

I want to be able to switch off (i.e. hide) blocks of math within `align` via a switch and have it replaced with white space.  I've found numerous examples of how to switch on/off text and even elements within an `align` environment but none of those really fit what I need (or worked for me in general).

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% SWITCH MATH ON(1)/OFF(0)
\def\showmath{1}
\newcommand{\mathsolution}[1]{
   \ifnum\showmath=1
   #1
   \fi

   \ifnum\showmath=0
   \vspace{2\baselineskip} \hspace{2cm}
   \fi
}

\begin{document}

Some text.
\mathsolution{
\begin{align*}
y = mx+b \\
y = mx+b 
\end{align*}
}
Some text.

\end{document}
```

I am currently trying to fuss around with the following bit of code to do this:

```
\ifnum\showmath=0
\vspace{2\baselineskip} \hspace{2cm}
\fi
```

Here the math doesn't get printed and some whitespace is inserted.  However, I want the whitespace to be roughly approximate to what the actual block of math takes up.

Note: Printing in white won't work here because it can still be copy/pasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the solution in a box and display either the box or a vspace of that height:

```
\newif\ifshowmath  % use \newif to define switches

\newenvironment{mathsolution}{
\setbox0\vbox\bgroup} % store solution in box 0
{\egroup  % end of box
\ifshowmath\par\box0  % display box
\else\vskip\ht0       % whitespace of height of box
\fi
}


\begin{document}
\showmathfalse
Hidden solution:
\begin{mathsolution}
\begin{align}
   x & = 12 \\
   y & = 42
\end{align}
\end{mathsolution}

\showmathtrue

Shown solution:
\begin{mathsolution}
\begin{align}
   x & = 12 \\
   y & = 42
\end{align}
\end{mathsolution}
\end{document}
```

That implementation is likely not very robust especially in combination with pagebreaks.

Comment: Is there anyway to set the switch to a simple 0/1 parameter rather than a true/false string?  So far this seems to be working for me.  I'm hoping a `samepage` environment helps alleviate any pagebreak issues.

Comment: You can replace the `\ifshowmath` by `\ifnum\showmath=0` (as in your MWE) in the `\newenvironment` and remove/replace all other occurrences of it.